# R Multiple/Logistic Regression with 3 Variables,Statistical Testing?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, statistical-test

I need some help with statistical testing codes. Basically I'm trying to study the relationship between age, political standing and views on cannabis legalisation. The dataset is the British Social Attitudes survey 2010.

```
bsa_2010 <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ubl9huokroj9jw8/bsa%202010.csv")
> dput(head(bsa_2010))
structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("England", 
"Scotland", "Wales"), class = "factor"), RSex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    RAge = c(75L, 34L, 81L, 25L, 33L, 76L), MarStat = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Living as married", "Married", 
    "Not married", "Separated or divorced after marrying", "Widowed"
    ), class = "factor"), ChildHh = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), WhPaper = structure(c(8L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 8L), .Label = c("(Scottish) Daily Express", 
    "(Scottish) Daily Mail", "Daily Mirror/ Scottish Mirror", 
    "Daily Record", "Daily Star", "Daily Telegraph", "Financial Times", 
    "Skip,not read paper normally", "The Guardian", "The Independent", 
    "The Sun/ Scottish Sun", "The Times"), class = "factor"), 
    PartyIDN = structure(c(2L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("British National Party (BNP)/ National Front", 
    "Conservative", "Don't know", "Green Party", "Labour", "Liberal Democrat", 
    "None", "Other answer (WRITE IN)", "Other party (WRITE IN)", 
    "Plaid Cymru", "Refused to say", "Scottish National Party", 
    "UK Independence Party (UKIP)/Veritas"), class = "factor"), 
    Partyid1 = structure(c(2L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("British National Party (BNP)/ National Front", 
    "Conservative", "Don't know", "Green Party", "Labour", "Liberal Democrat", 
    "None", "Other answer", "Other party", "Plaid Cymru", "Refusal", 
    "Scottish National Party", "UK Independence Party (UKIP)/Veritas"
    ), class = "factor"), PartyId2 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Conservative", "Green Party", "Labour", 
    "Liberal Democrat", "None", "Other party", "Other/DK/Ref"
    ), class = "factor"), Spend1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L), .Label = c("(None of these)", "Defence", "Education", 
    "Health", "Help for industry", "Housing", "Overseas aid", 
    "Police and prisons", "Public transport", "Roads", "Social security benefits"
    ), class = "factor"), Spend2 = structure(c(6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    9L, 10L), .Label = c("(None of these)", "Defence", "Education", 
    "Health", "Help for industry", "Housing", "Overseas aid", 
    "Police and prisons", "Public transport", "Roads", "Skip,no 1st priority", 
    "Social security benefits"), class = "factor"), RClassGp = structure(c(4L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Employers in small org; own account workers", 
    "Intermediate occupations", "Lower supervisory & technical occupations", 
    "Managerial & professional occups", "Not classifiable", "Semi-routine & routine occupations", 
    "Skip, never had a job+DK+NA last job"), class = "factor"), 
    RNSSECG = structure(c(4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("1.1", 
    "1.2", "Intermediate occupations", "Lower managerial and professional occupations", 
    "Lower supervisory & technical occupations", "Not classified", 
    "Routine occupations", "Semi-routine Occupations", "Small employers and own account workers"
    ), class = "factor"), CanLegal = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Taking cannabis should remain illegal", 
    "should be legal, only licenced shops"), class = "factor"), 
    RaceOri3 = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("ASIAN: of Bangladeshi origin", 
    "ASIAN: of Chinese origin", "ASIAN: of Indian origin", "ASIAN: of Pakistani origin", 
    "ASIAN: of other origin (WRITE IN)", "BLACK: of African origin", 
    "BLACK: of Caribbean origin", "MIXED ORIGIN (WRITE IN)", 
    "OTHER (WRITE IN)", "WHITE: of any origin"), class = "factor"), 
    Agecat1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("(18,28]", 
    "(28,38]", "(38,48]", "(48,58]", "(58,68]", "(68,78]", "(78,88]", 
    "(88,98]"), class = "factor"), Agecat2 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("(18,38]", "(38,58]", "(58,78]", 
    "(78,98]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Country", "RSex", 
"RAge", "MarStat", "ChildHh", "WhPaper", "PartyIDN", "Partyid1", 
"PartyId2", "Spend1", "Spend2", "RClassGp", "RNSSECG", "CanLegal", 
"RaceOri3", "Agecat1", "Agecat2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Variables used are: 
RAge (Age) 
PartyIDN (Political party identified) 
CanLegal (Cannabis Legalisation)

To simplify it, I've put ages into categories and kept only two of the biggest political parties.

```
bsa_2010$Agecat1 <- cut(bsa_2010$RAge, c(18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98))

Parties <- subset(bsa_2010, PartyIDN == "Conservative" | PartyIDN == "Labour")


Parties$PartyIDN <- factor(Parties$PartyIDN)
```

How would I carry out statistical testing to get P values on the relationship between age, politics and how they view cannabis legalisation?

Any help would be welcome, thank you!

Comment: Give us a sample of the dataset not a dropbox link. Just do `dput(head(bsa_2010))`

Comment: Is that right? I'm sorry, I'm new to the website and R!

Comment: Welcome! No paste the result of the command not the command as such! It will give you a sample of the data we can work with to provide a solution.

Comment: Do I just run dput(head(bsa_2010)) in R and copy/paste the output from R onto here? I'm really sorry I'm a mess

Comment: Yes exactly! this result we can copy paste in our Rsessions.

Comment: I've just done this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you also need some help with the basics so I would look [here https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) for the statistics part but the R part is easy (I'm going to consider your new age categories a factor not a continuous variable)...

```
bsa_2010$Agecat1 <- cut(bsa_2010$RAge, c(18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98))
Parties <- subset(bsa_2010, PartyIDN == "Conservative" | PartyIDN == "Labour")
Parties$PartyIDN <- factor(Parties$PartyIDN)
str(Parties)
Parties$Agecat1<-factor(Parties$Agecat1)
firstattempt <- glm(CanLegal ~ Agecat1 + PartyIDN, data = Parties, family = "binomial")
summary(firstattempt)
```

For what it's worth your cuts on Age don't help make the `R` commands or the statistics easier.  You could have just as easily done:

```
secondattempt <- glm(CanLegal ~ RAge + PartyIDN, data = Parties, family = "binomial")
summary(secondattempt)
```

It actually makes interpreting the data easier, which supports the hypothesis that age matters to the outcome but political party doesn't. You can see that with these very simple graphs

```
mosaicplot(xtabs(~CanLegal + PartyIDN, data = Parties))
mosaicplot(xtabs(~CanLegal + Agecat1, data = Parties))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm so new to R and the world of programming, everything confuses me at this point. Is there a way to extract the P values from a GLM? I've tried running Pchisq test on the null and residual deviances, is that right?

Comment: Again I recommend you read https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/ but to put is simply the command `summary(firstattempt)` does provide "p values" in the far right column for each term

Comment: Thank you! Removing all the age categories made it easier and I now know how to read the Pvalues. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome feel free to flag the answer as correct